# CyberSource payment processor error: Unsupported currency

Tags: java

I am supposed to integrate a CyberSource payment gateway:
My request data :

```
request.put( "ccAuthService_run", "true" ); 
request.put( "ccCaptureService_run", "true" );
request.put( "merchantReferenceCode", "your_merchant_reference_code" );                  
request.put( "billTo_firstName", "John" );
request.put( "card_accountNumber", "4111111111111111" ); 
request.put( "card_expirationMonth", "12" ); 
request.put( "card_expirationYear", "2020" ); 
request.put( "purchaseTotals_currency", "USD" );  
request.put("purchaseTotals_grandTotalAmount", "100.00");
```

I am always getting this error response:

```
decision=REJECT invalidField_0=purchaseTotals_currency     
ccAuthReply_avsCode=2 reasonCode=102    
merchantReferenceCode=your_merchant_reference_code 
invalidField_=purchaseTotals_currency
```

It looks like my merchant ID is not configured with a valid currency. Please help me.